# Excel auto Text formatting based on values within a range of cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

Need help finding a way to auto format a text response based on values in another set of cells. There are 3 values in Column B,C, and D and depending on the highest value of the three, the adjacent column (E) needs to automatically create a text response.

If the largest number from column B, C, or D is Between 85 and 105 then the box in column E should read single. If the highest value exceeds 105 then column E should read double. If the highest value is below 85 then column e should stay blank.

I have tried IF statements but they don't seem to work as their are two conditions that must be considered.

[image: Picture of issue in question]

Answer (score 0):

You want a nested IF:

```
=IF(MAX(B4:D4)>105,"Double",IF(max(B4:D4)>=85,"Single",""))
```

If the max is greater than 105 it will return "Double", If not then it must be less than or equal to 105.

If it is then greater than 85 then it must be between the two and we do not need to test it again.

If neither the first two are true then it must be less than 85 and therefore it should return blank.

Comment: @Kyle please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.  It is something only you can do.